# Create an Azure Web App Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, web-applications

Hi I'm currently refreshing my knowledge in C# programming.

I wanted to translate the manual way of creating a Web App in Microsoft Azure (Classic) into the C# language.

(Manual way - New > Compute > Web App > Custom Create > ...etc.. )

Whenever I search through google about this topic all it gives me is to literally create a "WebApp" in Visual Studio. (File > New > ...etc...) However, what I am looking for is how to create an Azure Web App programatically via C# - how to interact with the Management UI of the Classic Azure Portal to create a web app.

Anyone familiar to do this? Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: You want to interact with the portal via C#? you're not looking to simply interact with the API?

Comment: @MichaelB Yes sir. Is there a way or are there any libraries or APIs I could use to interact with the UI of the Azure Classic Portal and perform basic operations on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work on the available code Microsoft posted in GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net

I re-coded some and just acquired the functions that I only need for my program to work. :)

Answer (score 5):

To create an azure website easily using C#, you can use "Windows Azure Management Libraries". This SDK is a wrapper arround "Azure Service Management" API.

[Here](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries) is a introduction from Braddy Gaster an a [blog post](http://blogs.infinitesquare.com/b/tranise/archives/windows-azure-management-librairies-introduction-et-authentification#.VzRHyfmLQ2x), to get credentials from an Azure Tenant an work with ASM Api.

Then you will be able to create a website with something like this :

```
using (var AwsManagement = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites.WebSiteManagementClient(azureCredentials))
{

    WebSiteCreateParameters parameters = new WebSiteCreateParameters()
    {
            Name = "myAws",
            // this Service Plan must be created before
            ServerFarm = "myServiceplan",
     };

      await AwsManagement.WebSites.CreateAsync("myWebSpace", parameters, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web site by using a POST request that includes the name of the web site and other information in the request body. You can check the code example for ASM [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/WebSite/WebSiteManagement/Generated/WebSiteOperations.cs#LC1007).